# How can a list of (distinct) values be created from a variable containing comma separated entries?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a user generated variable (KEYWORDS) in an APEX report (saved in a table named APR) that allows users to enter multiple (comma-separated) values. I want to set up a list of distinct values that have been previously used to allow future select via a pop-up LOV.

I have managed to create a distinct list using

```
SELECT distinct regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
is not null 
;
```

where `select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR` is: `'test,test,TEST2,test,TEST2,test,TEST2,test3'`

and `select keywords from APR` consists of 6 rows:

```
test
test,TEST2
test,TEST2
test
TEST2
test3
```

My issue comes with trying to implement this within the Edit LOV query.

```
select (select distinct regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
is not null) as display_value, 

(select distinct regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
is not null) as return_value 

  from APR
 order by 1
```

This code is validated successfully within the edit LOV section but no values are shown in the pop-up LOV. Pasting into the SQL commands I receive the following error message: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: what is the difference between display_value and return_value values

Comment: No difference between display_value and return_value values - if there's a way to simplify this / assign to both at the same time then certainly happy to implement (I'm pretty new to sql). The pop-up LOV should show display values for the user to select, and then return the selection to edit the table (i.e. no labels are used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query you posted is invalid; `listagg` requires `within group` clause.

Anyway: I'd suggest you to use that query (which you probably have correctly written) as data source, something like this:

```
with t_data as
  (select listagg(keywords, ',') within group (order by null) col 
   from apr
  )
select col display_value,
       col return_value
from t_data
order by col
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the expected result?

Code :-

```
   WITH apr_new AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT regexp_substr(keywords,'[^,]+',1,level) keywords_new
       FROM (SELECT LISTAGG(keywords,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY keywords) keywords FROM apr) apr
       CONNECT BY regexp_substr(keywords,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL
   ) SELECT
       keywords_new AS display_value,
       keywords_new AS return_value
     FROM apr_new ORDER BY 1;
```

Result :-

TEST2   TEST2

TEST3   TEST3

test    test

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is the correct looking result (assuming represents two columns for display and return value) but I get an error when running your code: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: executed successfully for me . could you please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Littlefoot, using that framework

Using

```
with t_data as
(select distinct regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') within group (order by null) from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) col from dual 
    connect by regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') within group (order by null)from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
is not null )
select col display_value,
       col return_value
from t_data
order by col
```

or

```
with t_data as
(select distinct regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) col from dual 
    connect by regexp_substr((select LISTAGG(KEYWORDS, ',') from APR), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
is not null )
select col display_value,
       col return_value
from t_data
order by col
```

generates the same results. The latter works despite listagg apparently requiring within group clause (interested to know if this could lead to any issues down the line).